# How can a data frame be transformed into a string with a csv format on R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I don't want to write a csv into a file, but to get a string representation of the dataframe with a csv format (to send it over the network).

I'm using R.NET, if it helps to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not limited to `base` functions, you may try `readr::format_csv`.

```
library(readr)
format_csv(iris[1:2, 1:3])
# [1] "Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length\n5.1,3.5,1.4\n4.9,3.0,1.4\n"
```

Comment: @RichScriven yeah, this answer seems to be the easiest; although it requires an additional package, using existing tools should be encouraged.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a single string in csv format, you could capture the output from `write.csv`.

Let's use `mtcars` as an example:

```
paste(capture.output(write.csv(mtcars)), collapse = "\n")
```

This reads back into R fine with `read.csv(text = ..., row.names = 1)`.  You can make adjustments for the printing of row names and other attributes in `write.csv`.

Comment: It works but it appends a column with the rows' ids (e.i. 1,2,...,n)

Comment: @LayGonzález - You can adjust things like that in `write.csv`.  For row names, it's `row.names = FALSE` to leave them off.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
write.csv(mtcars, textConnection("output", "w"), row.names=FALSE)
```

which will create the variable `output` in the global environment and store it in a character vector.

You can do

```
paste0(output, collapse="\n")
```

to make it one big character string, similar to Rich's answer (but `paste0()` is marginally faster).